# Java Spring RequestContext test throws NullPointerException even with MockHttpServletRequest

Tags: java, spring, nullpointerexception, guava

I'm writing test for `RequestContextHolder`. I got the tests passed but then after I refactored I got NullPointerException but can't figure out why.

Here's the code.

```
    String processorName = "<UNKNOWN>".intern();
    Optional<HttpServletRequest> request = Optional.of(((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest());
    String procName = (String) request.get().getAttribute(CONTROLLER_NAME);

    if (!Strings.isEmpty(procName)) {
        processorName = procName;
    }

    return processorName;
```

And here's my tests

```
@Test
public void testProcessorName() throws Exception {
    MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
    request.setAttribute(CONTROLLER_NAME, "default");
    RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(new ServletRequestAttributes(request));

    String processorName = halUtils.processorName();
    assertEquals("default", processorName);
}

@Test
public void testProcessorNameWithoutAttribute() throws Exception {
    MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
    RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(new ServletRequestAttributes(request));

    String processorName = halUtils.processorName();
    assertEquals("<UNKNOWN>", processorName);
}

@Test
public void testProcessorNameWithoutRequest() throws Exception {
    String processorName = halUtils.processorName();
    assertEquals("<UNKNOWN>", processorName);
}
```

Then I refactored to be a one liner but I got NullPointerException instead.

```
public String processorName() {
    return Optional.of(((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest().getAttribute(CONTROLLER_NAME)).orElse("<UNKNOWN>".intern()).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is basically:

```
return Optional.of(null).orElse("<UNKNOWN>".intern()).toString();
```

Doing so will give you a NullPointerException, because the return of `getAttribute(CONTROLLER_NAME)` is null, and `Optional.of(..)` does not accept null parameters, while in your original code, you were testing its value with `Strings.isEmpty(..)`.